# How to search for two or more subjects in SQL

Tags: python, sql, select, search

I can only search for one subject or person each time, but I want to see if I can use only on piece of code to do whatever that will take me more tries.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Suspects
WHERE Age BETWEEN "35" AND "50" AND Build = "Overweight" AND Gender = "M" AND Facial_features = "Beard";

SELECT *
FROM Suspects
WHERE Hair_colour = "Bald" AND Other_features = "tattoo";
```

Comment: In standard `sql` you would use single-quotes for 'strings' normally, and your Age column is not numeric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do you mean by subjects? Do you want to get two suspects as a response without running two queries?

If you put all "Where" clauses under the same select query, then you will get more than one result if there are more than one subject that matches this criteria.

Try this:
SELECT* FROM Suspects WHERE Age BETWEEN "35" AND "50" AND Build = "Overweight" AND Gender = "M" AND Facial_features = "Beard" AND Hair_colour = "Bald" AND Other_features = "tattoo"